# Can I see the exact time to miliseconds of sending input to the web page in Devtool?

Tags: javascript, html, devtools

Can I see the exact time to miliseconds of sending input to the web page in Devtool? Is it to be found somewhere in the network section? More specifically, when I click a button to activate the dice roll for example, a couple of miliseconds later I might get a response from the server and I want to know when exactly did I click the dice roll button? Btw, by DevTool mean the F12 key in the browser.

Comment: What browser? Dev tools aren't the same across the board.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. And if you get it, is your clock synchronized? Maybe it is better if you save the timestamp in your click-handler?

Answer (score 0):

In the dice event handler write:

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(
    d.getHours().toString().padStart(2, "0") + ":" +
    d.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0") + ":" +
    d.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, "0") + "," +
    d.getMilliseconds().toString().padStart(3, "0"));
```

Then in the network tab you can copy all to a notepad and you can check the HH:mm:ss,mmm of each request/response.

Answer (score 0):

Every DOM `Event` has a [`.timestamp` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/timeStamp) attached to it with the time you are looking for. An event handler will be able to read that value and e.g. log it to the console. But no, it won't show up in the network section (unless e.g. you pass it to the request as a parameter).

The closest you'd get is by profiling the [initiators](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#initiators-dependencies) of the relevant request. In general however, a click event immediately schedules the request, and *that* time is recorded and visible in the network section.